# PyQt5 - How to set QPixmap to black?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpixmap

I've recently started to learn PyQt5 a bit.

But I'm struggling to set a [`QPixmap`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) to fully black.

Is there any QPixmap function on how to set it to black?

For example something like `self.screen.setPixmap()`?

Comment: [`pixmap.fill(Qt.black)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#fill).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it with:
black = QPixmap(16,16)
black.fill(Qt.black)
self.screen.setPixmap(black)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue like [suggested by musicamente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72408545/pyqt5-how-to-set-qpixmap-to-black#comment127915928_72408545) using [`pixmap.fill(Qt.black)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#fill):

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

pixmap = QPixmap(16,16)
pixmap.fill(Qt.black)  #  fill the map with black

self.screen.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).